# How can I transfer files from Google AI platform training job to my another compute instance or local machine?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Any ideas how I automatically send some files (mainly Tensorflow models) after training in Google AI platform to another compute instance or my local machine? I would like to run in my trainer for instance something like this `os.system(scp -r ./file1 user@host:/path/to/folder)`. Of course I don’t need to use scp. It’s just an example. Is there such a possibility in Google? There is no problem to transfer files from job to Google Cloud Storage like this `os.system('gsutil cp ./example_file gs://my_bucket/path/')`. However when I try for example `os.system('gcloud compute scp ./example_file my_instance:/path/')` to transfer data from my AI platform job to another instance I get `Your platform does not support SSH`. Any ideas how can I do this?

**UPDATE**
Maybe there is a possibility to automatically download all the files from the google cloud storage which are in chosen folder? So I would for instance upload data from my job instance to the google cloud storage folder and my another instance would automatically detect changes and download all the new files?

**UPDATE2**
I found `gsutil rsync` but I am not sure whether it can be constantly running in the background? At this point the only solution that comes to my mind is to use cron job in the backend and run `gsutil rsync` for example every 10 minutes. But is doesn't seem to be optimal solution. Maybe there is a built-in tool or another better idea?

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` command makes the contents under destination the same as the contents under source, by copying any missing files/objects (or those whose data has changed), and (if the -d option is specified) deleting any extra files/objects. source must specify a directory, bucket, or bucket subdirectory. But it command does not run in background.

Remember that the Notebook you're using is in fact a VM running JupyterLab, based on that you could run the command `rsync` once Tensorflow finished to created the files and sync it with a directory in another instance trying something like:

```
import os
os.system("rsync -avrz Tensorflow/outputs/filename root@ip:Tensorflow/otputs/file")
```

I suggest you to take a look in the `rsync` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) to know all the options available to use that command.